# Print and Export buttons redirect to login database server in Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-xi

I created a empty **DataSet** and table ("DataTable1") and then created a Crystal Report using that DataSet and set source for DataSet in code behind.

```
        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = businessService.GetEmpDetails(SetDBSchema())
        dt.TableName = "DataTable1"

        Dim Report As ReportDocument = New ReportDocument()
        Report.Load(Server.MapPath("EvaluationReport.rpt"))
        Report.Database.Tables("DataTable1").SetDataSource(dt)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

        Report.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "Customers")
```

When I trying to export or print report using CrystalReportViewer toolbar redirect to login to database server.

```
 <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" HasExportButton="True" PrintMode="Pdf" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

Also ExportToHttpResponse not working.

I think these issues arise because of assigning DataSet in code, any idea how to overcome these?

Answer (score 0):

I got where it went wrong. CrystalReportViewer was inside of **Update Panel** and removal of Update Panel work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
 Report.Database.Tables("DataTable1").SetDataSource(dt)
```

use :

```
  Report.SetDataSource(dt)
```

remove:

```
  CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

add:

Report.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "Customers")

add:

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

no need for the export button if you have an asp button else you can keep it